# Djangoのローカライズがうまくいかない

Tags: python, django

公式ドキュメントを参考にしてDjangoでローカライズを行おうとしております。

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view

**urls.py**に

```
(r'^localize/', welcome_translated),
```

を追加。

**settings.py**には

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', # localize
```

のように追加。

さらにこれらはどちらもTrueにしました。

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

更に、今回使うjaの設定方法がドキュメントによって違うので

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ja', _('Japanese')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

も

```
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ja', gettext('Japanese')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
```

を両方試しました。※違いがわかりません。

**views.py**には、先ほどのurls.pyから呼ばれる最小限の以下のコードを追加しました。

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import get_language, activate, ugettext_lazy as _

def welcome_translated(request):
    language = 'ja'
    cur_language = get_language()

    try:
        activate(language)
        text = _("login")
    finally:
        activate(cur_language)

    return HttpResponse(text) # これがきちんとログインと出るべき
```

直打ちで'ja'をactivateしており、

```
locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

もあり、

```
msgid "login"
msgstr "ログイン"
```

のように設定しています。

しかしながら、Webブラウザでは「login」が表示されてしまいます。
「ログイン」が出るはずです。

しかし、テンプレートでも

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "title" %}
```

とやっても一向に「ログイン」が表示されません。

ドキュメントの例には、

> Calling this function with the value ‘de’ will give you "Willkommen"

とあったので、そもそもdjango.poに自分で設定するものではなく、何らかの形で自動的に変換するものかと思い、

'de'を設定して、「welcome」にしたら、ドイツ語の「Willkommen」が表示されるのかと思いましたが、「welcome」がそのまま表示されてしまいました。
なぜでしょうか？

ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`django.po` を編集したあとに、

```
$ python manage.py compilemessages
```

していますか？これで、`.po` から `.mo` が生成されます。
さらに `runserver` は手動で再起動する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさしくその通りでした！ 

Noteで「Gettext utilities」を強調してるのに気が付きませんでした。 

例にあった、welcomeもpoファイルに翻訳を自分で記載しているという前提の説明なんですよね？

とりあえず、ビューでもテンプレートでも動作しました。 activateを永続的にする仕組を作らないといけないかもしれませんが。

Comment: そうですね。`makemessages` で作成された `.po` を自分で編集する感じです。永続化の仕組みも既に `django` にあったはずです。おそらく `request.session['django_language']` とかで取れたとおもいます。